# Procedural texturing for inside of cherry

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, procedural, shader-nodes

[image]

Hello,
I’m wondering how to create a procedural texture for the inside of a cherry (just the “meat”) as pictured above. Help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It’ll probably involve a noise texture or two, one for displacement, and the clearcoat function of Principled BSDF. Beyond that is opinion-based.

Comment: And maybe a subdivision surface for the meaty transparency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a try, I've used a *Noise Texture* for the red color and mixed it with an *Attribute Color* (I've vertex painted all the borders to make them darker). Also a mix between two *Noise Texture* nodes (a big and a small one) to make the bumps. Put the *Roughness* at its minimum:

[image]

[image]

Here is the vertex paint:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it’s just what I need!